# C# get list from property and get it type

Tags: c#, list, types

I need get a type of list element.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xClass = new XClass();
        xClass.Do();
    }
}

public class XClass
{
    public List<string> list1 = new List<string>();

    public List<string> list2 { get; set; }

    public void Do()
    {
       // first
        Console.WriteLine("Type = {0}", GetListType(list1));

        // second
        var propertyList = this.GetType().GetProperty("list2"); // i get list from reflection

        // Create instance of list2
        var newList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance((typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(propertyList.PropertyType))); 

        Console.WriteLine("Type = {0}", GetListType(newList));
    }

    private Type GetListType(IEnumerable list)
    {
        return list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

Output:

Type = System.String

Type = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

I need to get "System.String" in second case

You can test code here http://ideone.com/uLkfBx

Comment: Is it intentional that `newList` is a `List<List<string>>` ?

Comment: Hint: what is `propertyList.PropertyType`? Try outputting it. Generally, try not just snapping pieces together but *thinking what your code does*. It's been known to help on occasion.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

The statement `var newList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance((typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(propertyList.PropertyType)));` creates an instance of a generic List that contains the type of `list2`. So `newList` is of type `List<List<string>>` hence your result is correct.